# Why can't create a directory when there is a file with the same name as the directory that I want to create?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How come I can't create a folder when there is a file named the same with the folder that I am about to create?

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Feb 24 15:01 abc

$ mkdir abc
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘abc’: File exists
```

Is there way to create the "abc" folder without changing the name of the file?

Comment: You can't have both. If you could what would `./abc` refer to, the file or the directory? Filesystem operations aren't context-sensitive.

Comment: `Is there way to create the "abc" folder without changing the name of the file?` - no, there isn't but since you're on Linux the filesystem is probably case-sensitive so you can create `ABC`, `Abc` etc.

Comment: Oh, I have used linux for 1 year, only now i heard such thing.. lol OK, no choice but to accept that.  Your explaination is reasonable. I came from windows os, there is no such problem in windows os. Thx

Comment: Ummm ... no, it's the same in windows.  Just because you've set explorer to hide a file's extension doesn't mean its name is just what you see.  Open a `cmd`, type `echo what > abc` ... then try `md abc`. And you'll get the "error message" `A subdirectory or file abc already exists`.

Comment: Thanks tink, i remember now.. my fault. It is actual due to that my default we always attach and extension to a file, so we can have abc.txt, and folder name abc..  that's why i remember wrongly that windows can have same filename of folder and file in a location.  my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "folder" or a directory is really just a file containing links to other files. So it is only logical that you can not have 2 similar records inside a single list of some directory. Not having to check other attributes apart from the names in each application makes initial file access much easier and quicker than it would be otherwise.